# Columbia Integration Bee 2022 Finals

Tags: definite-integrals, contest-math, trigonometric-integrals

I want to find the definite integral shown below, but I'm not quite sure where to start. The fastest solution apparently involved some sort of change of variables, but I can't quite find a substitution that seems to work.
$$\int_0^{π/2} \frac {\cos^{2022}(x)}{\cos^{2022}(x)+\sin^{2022}(x)}\mathrm dx$$

Comment: There is in fact a very convenient change of variables: as a hint, try taking advantage of the symmetry of the denominator and the relationship between sine and cosine (the bounds are also important)

Comment: Any more hints? It's been a long day and my brain seems pretty asleep right now.

Comment: Try the change $y=\pi/2-x$ and see what you get. Once you do this change try to relate the original integral with the new one.

Comment: From the denominator it can be very easy to get stuck in tunnel vision trying to do Pythagorean stuff, but the key identity is the *other* fundamental right angle trig identity

Comment: That’s lovely. Thank you all for your help.